# Como reduzir o tamanho dessa função que contém vários if?

Tags: javascript, funções, if, for

Queria pensar em uma lógica que desse pra diminuir o tamanho desse código, pois ele acaba se repetindo.

É uma calculadora de experiência pra um jogo. Você coloca seu nível atual e o nível que quer chegar. O jogo tem nível normal que vai de 1 até 399 e o nível master que vai de 400 até 1300.

Basicamente preciso verificar se tanto o nível atual quanto o nível desejado estão na categoria correta (se está no normal ou master).

Observem que tanto o `if` do `currentLevel` quanto a do `desiredLevel` são praticamente idênticos, só muda mesmo que um é pra o `current` e o outro é pra o `desired`.

Não liguem pro *array* ter mais variáveis, eu só trouxe a parte que me interessa aqui. A função tem mais coisa além disso.

```js
let checkfields = [currentLevel, desiredLevel, currentExp, expSec, hoursDay]

            function checkFieldInsert(normalInitialLevel, masterInitialLevel){
                for (let i = 0; i <= checkfields.length; i++){
                    if (checkfields[i] == currentLevel){
                        if (levelMaster.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) < 400){
                            alert(`this ${checkfields[i].value} is not master level`)
                            break
                        } 
                        else if (levelNormal.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) >= 400){
                            alert(`this ${checkfields[i].value} is not normal level`)
                            break
                        }
                    } else if (checkfields[i] == desiredLevel){
                        if (levelMaster.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) < 400){
                            alert(`this ${checkfields[i].value} is not master level`)
                            break
                        } 
                        else if (levelNormal.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) >= 400){
                            alert(`this ${checkfields[i].value} is not normal level`)
                            break
                        }
                    }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As duas principais condições são quase idênticas, só uma subexpressão é diferente e o que executa quando entra em cada um é idêntico, então realmente não faz sentido ter duas condições. O código tem um padrão idêntico exceto por um detalhe, então fazer ficar só uma vez é fácil e apenas muda a subexpressão, então ele entra sendo uma subexpressão sendo verdadeira OU a outra que está no outro `if` sendo verdadeira também. Coloquei entre parênteses porque ela precisa ser feita  antes do resto.

Também tirei a comparação com `true` porque ele já espera um `true` não faz sentido fazer essa comparação, o que já reduz um pouco o tamanho do código.

Dá para reduzir um pouco mais mas acho que não compensa, começa ficar amontoado e confuso.

Não garanto que faz o que deseja, só fiz a redução do código sem contexto.

```
function checkFieldInsert(normalInitialLevel, masterInitialLevel){
    for (let i = 0; i <= checkfields.length; i++){
        if ((checkfields[i] == currentLevel || checkfields[i] == desiredLevel) && levelNormal.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) >= 400 || levelMaster.checked && parseInt(checkfields[i].value) < 400){
            if (levelMaster.checked){
                alert(`Level ${checkfields[i].value} is not master level`)
                break
            } else if (levelNormal.checked){
                alert(`Level ${checkfields[i].value} is not normal level`)
                break
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SimpleCode.js).

Comment: Nossa, funcionou! Não sabia que eu podia usar parênteses dessa forma... Eu tinha tentado fazer exatamente a mesma coisa que você fez, mas sem o parênteses e acabou não dando certo. Muito obrigado.